# Java - Killing all parent and child thread spawned through scheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a thread that keeps polling at fixed rate using `scheduledExecutorService` when the service starts (servlet's contextInitialized). This thread again spawns threads at fixed rate using scheduledExecutorService which are the child thread for the first polling thread. Will calling `scheduledExecutorService.shutdownNow();` on the first polling thread also kill my child threads?

If no, how could all the parent and child thread be killed on servlet's contextDestroyed?

Thanks

Comment: What is preventing you to actually run and test whatever you said?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `shutdownNow()` will cause all executing threads to be canceled and will stop any `Runnable` or `Callable` objects from being submitted to the executor. Any `Runnable` or `Callable` objects that were submitted but not started are returned in a list (represented as `ScheduledFutureTask` instances). Cancel in this case means that each `Thread` in the pool that is executing the `Runnable` and `Callable` instances will be interrupted and an `InterruptedException` will be thrown from within the `Runnable`/`Callable`. If this exception is ignored or handled within an infinite loop, the `Runnable` will continue to execute forever, even though it has been canceled by the executor. As quoted from the [`ExecutorService#shutdownNow()` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()):

> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing
>   actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will
>   cancel via `Thread.interrupt()`, so any task that fails to respond to
>   interrupts may never terminate.

If you are submitting the child `Runnable` (or `Callable`) objects to the same executor that the parent `Runnable` was started on, then yes, the child `Runnable` objects will be canceled as well. Moreover, they will be "killed" so long as they halt executing upon receiving an `InterruptedException`.

For example, running the following code

```
public class ParentRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final static AtomicInteger CHILD_ID = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final ScheduledExecutorService executor;

    public ParentRunnable(ScheduledExecutorService executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            System.out.println("Started parent");

            while (true) {
                ChildRunnable child = new ChildRunnable(getChildName());
                executor.schedule(child, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                System.out.println("Submitted " + child.getName());
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Parent thread was interrupted and is stopping");
        }
    }

    private static String getChildName() {
        return "Child " + CHILD_ID.addAndGet(1);
    }
}

public class ChildRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final String name;

    public ChildRunnable(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            System.out.println("Started " + name);

            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(name + " was interrupted and is stopping");
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);
        executor.execute(new ParentRunnable(executor));
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        List<Runnable> unstartedRunnables = executor.shutdownNow();
        executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Unstarted runnables: " + unstartedRunnables);
    }
}
```

results in the following output:

```
Started parent
Submitted Child 1
Started Child 1
Submitted Child 2
Started Child 2
Submitted Child 3
Started Child 3
Submitted Child 4
Started Child 4
Submitted Child 5
Parent thread was interrupted and is stopping
Child 3 was interrupted and is stopping
Child 4 was interrupted and is stopping
Child 2 was interrupted and is stopping
Child 1 was interrupted and is stopping
Unstarted runnables: [java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@46f5f779]
```

The code above starts a `ParentRunnable` which in turn submits a `ChildRunnable` to be started every second and then sleeps for 2 seconds. Each `ChildRunnable` does nothing but sleep for 1 second, but both the `ParentRunnable` and `ChildRunnable` are responsive to `InterruptedException`, breaking out of their respective infinite loops and ending the execution of the `Runnable`. The `main` method starts the `ParentRunnable`, lets the `ParentRunnable` execute for 10 seconds, terminates the executor using `shutdownNow()`, and then prints the `Runnable` objects that have *not* yet been started by the executor.

Looking at the results, we can see that 4 of the `ChildRunnable` objects have been started  and are subsequently cancelled when the executor is shutdown using `shutdownNow()` and the remaining `ChildRunnable` is returned in the list of unstarted `Runnables` (represented by a `ScheduledFutureTask` object).

This program works because of the following assumptions:

1. The `ChildRunnable` instances are submitted to the same executor as the `ParentRunnable`
2. The `ParentRunnable` and `ChildRunnable` instances halt execution upon receiving an `InterruptedException`

For more information, see section 6 and 7 of [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) and consult the [`ExecutorService` interface documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).